# In Rust, what's the pattern for when you need a reference-holding struct to sometimes own its referenced data?

Tags: design-patterns, rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following data structure:

```rust
struct ReferenceHoldingStruct<'a> {
    pub prop: &'a str
}
```

This pattern is often useful, especially in parsers (my use-case), for "giving" a struct some piece of string data without re-allocating it:

```rust
fn generate_these_1<'a>(input: &'a str) -> ReferenceHoldingStruct<'a> {
    ReferenceHoldingStruct { prop: input }
}
```

However, I've got a case where I have a struct like the above, but in one spot I need to generate instances that are "independent"; i.e. they own their own data:

```rust
fn generate_these_2<'a>(input: String) -> ReferenceHoldingStruct<'a> {
    ReferenceHoldingStruct { prop: input.as_str() }
}
```

I understand why this version doesn't work: the String being referred to doesn't live anywhere where Rust can see that it will hang around to keep fulfilling the struct's `&str` reference. I thought maybe this would work:

```rust
fn generate_these_2<'a>(input: String) -> (String, ReferenceHoldingStruct<'a>) {
    (input, ReferenceHoldingStruct { prop: input.as_str() })
}
```

because at least the String won't get immediately dropped. I thought maybe Rust could figure out that this tuple contains both the reference and the data it refers to, and that they'd therefore be valid as long as they're kept together like this. But no dice: this still doesn't work. It treats the reference as a borrow and the move to the tuple as a move, and you can't do both "at the same time".

So, I understand the problem, but not where to go from here. What's the standard practice for this kind of situation?

Comment: Could you use [Cow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think Cow is relevant because this is a question of lifetimes, not mutability

Comment: @brundolf Cow is not only about mutability, it's a type which can hold an owned or a referenced version of a type, which is exactly what you're looking for. Although it does require the reference to be convertible to the owned type, strs will work out of the box.

Comment: Your last version doesn't work because Rust expects that values can always be memcpy'd during moving. There are some Pin types for other cases but it is better to avoid pin if not necessary because it introduce complexity to code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example with `Cow` (mentioned in the comments):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct ReferenceHoldingStruct<'a> {
    pub prop: Cow<'a, str>
}

fn generate_these_1<'a>(input: &'a str) -> ReferenceHoldingStruct<'a> {
    ReferenceHoldingStruct { prop: Cow::Borrowed(input) }
}

fn generate_these_2<'a>(input: String) -> ReferenceHoldingStruct<'a> {
    ReferenceHoldingStruct { prop: Cow::Owned(input) }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could store something that implements [`Borrow<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) instead:

```
struct ReferenceHoldingStruct<S: Borrow<str>> {
    pub prop: S,
}
```

The bound on `S` allows it to be anything that can be borrowed as a `&str`. This could be a `&str` itself, or an owned `String` (or anything else that implements `Borrow<str>`). As there are blanket impls that implement `Borrow<T>` on both `T` and `&T`, this approach can be used to either store a reference or own a value of any type, not just `str`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d85ed5c8255c2d903a9d3df972ae2f75)

Comment: Woah. That's really cool and just might work. I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: `Borrow<T>` is great, but you might find your use-case is better suited to `Cow<str>` if all you need is "either a string I borrow or a string I own"

Comment: @JMAA you make a good point. `Cow` is an easier drop-in replacement if you are using `Clone` types like `str`/`String`, but the `Borrow` approach, unlike `Cow`, works for non-`Clone` types.